# Directv in to a antenna tv port hole

Tags: television

I have DirecTV: Next to the satellite is a 4 way splitter one of the port holes is not being used, can I screw a coaxial cable to it and run it to my garage than screw the other end of the cable to the cable port hole on my tv (that is now receiving antenna signals only) and be able to receive good reception and more channels ? I have no cable boxes just tv & remote , it would be straight from the satellite splitter to the back of the tv in to the cable port hole .

Comment: I believe that would get you nothing.  That splitter port is to supply a signal to a cable box that can turn the Sat signal into something that the TV can use.  Without the decoding box the signal is worthless.

Comment: If by satellite you mean a box that sits on a table inside the house, then probably yes.  If you mean the dish itself, probably not.

Comment: You would be using the dish as a local antenna.  You would pick up more channels than having nothing plugged into the TV, but the digital ones would be sparse.  You could get the same effect by taking a coax to wire adapter and soldering the wire ends to a bed frame or other metal object.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *no* set-top boxes anywhere in the house, then the signal coming out of the dish is *probably* processed and ready for the TV to use. The best way to find out is to give it a try.

If running a cable to this TV would be a hassle, bring this TV to one of the other cable ends (behind one of your other TVs) first and swap the cable from that TV to this TV and make sure it works. You may also want to swap the cable at the dish end to make sure that the output on that connector is functional. If so, swap the cable back and run a cable to the new location in the garage.

Of course, you *might* be paying for a fixed number of TVs in the house and this might violate your contract. I wouldn't want to give you any advice that might end up with you in trouble.